# How can I pass a cookie held by CookieManager to Jsoup in Android?

Tags: android, cookies, jsoup, httpclient, session-cookies

I have several apps in which I am receiving a cookie from the webview on logged in webpages and reuse it directly with jsoup to scrape content as follows:

```
final String url = "https://need.authentication.com";


// -- Android Cookie part here --
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();

String cookie = cm.getCookie(url); // returns cookie for url

// ...

// -- JSoup part here --
// Jsoup uses cookies as "name/value pairs"
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://need.authentication.com").cookie(url, cookie).get();
```

This doesn't work for all urls. Receiving the cookie is never a problem but jsoup sometimes can not use the cookie.

All i would like to do now is add this existing cookie to a httpclient or another non-deprecated option to download the page and then hand it to jsoup for further scraping as I have the feeling jsoup isn't handling cookies correctly.

Jsoup debug is only showing:

```
03-19 03:06:16.394 1317-3369/mysource.internationsexpress W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
03-19 03:06:16.394 1317-3369/mysource.internationsexpress W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
03-19 03:06:16.394 1317-3369/mysource.internationsexpress W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
03-19 03:06:16.394 1317-3369/mysource.internationsexpress W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
```

and for more info the cookie looks like this:

```
__indbg=481084b1-3d71-461a-b6e1-93d; 
__gads=ID=0058c3ccb75f72f2:T=1458162316:S=ALN; 
INSESSION=ct8njokkc4uadlmjjg8a3gvp1ng4m0acvvveea66bkpmn32fvc; 
INEP=%5B%22nw01_101_B_0%22%2C%22mp04_103_B_0%22%2C%22in01_244; 
WASLOGGEDIN=1; 
INREMEMBERME=cHlMQlRVbzVOUkhJTU5kU25tMlplZ2RvNWxvbkN4TmdsR0RBVWp6Qkp6dkpONW1Tb2o3MH; 
INBP=mobile; 
__utmt=1; 
__utma=68558281.1607821733.1458162272.1458240416.1; 
__utmb=68558281.1.10.1458327475; 
__utmc=68558281; 
__utmz=68558281.1458162272.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); 
__utmv=68558281.|2=community=sanj=1^3=loggedIn=1=1^5=experiment=%7Cst01_267_B_2%7Cmt01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cookie(name, value)` expects the name of the cookie not its related url.

Try this instead:

```
doc = Jsoup //
       .connect("https://need.authentication.com") //
       .header("Cookie", cookie) //
       .get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephan, but unfortunately it doesn't work either. Same as before. I made an edit to my question and showed a bit more debug info and how the cookie looks. I read that jsoup is not necessarily handling sessions and such well, so my thought is to make a URLConnection and pass the result of that to jsoup for parsing. here i don't know how with the cookie either though.

Comment: @SunnySonic Try to login to `need.authentication.com` with a browser  while spying the exchanges between the site and the browser. Analyze the headers exchanged and reproduced them in your code. The problem, at first sight, can come from cookies, another header, some javascript code to run or a clever footprint detection on the site itself. In either case URLConnection won't help. Last word, on Android platform, prefer the use of Volley.

Comment: Thank you Stephan. I found the problem now. Your suggestion works but the webpage is adding the tags i want to scrape for dynamically from Java script. Since Jsoup only scrapes html it won't work. I read about selenium and such to solve my problem now, or do you have a better idea?

Comment: @SunnySonic You can try ui4j as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. I will look into it. Accepted your answer since it solved the first problem i had, even though it wasn't the final issue.